# How to make a duel between knight with a greatsword and mage with a one-handed sword fair?

Tags: fight, swords

My hero is fighting using a longsword. He also knows some basic/intermediate spells so he could for example conjure a shield, throw fire, and things like that. He is currently saving his lady and to do that, he must first fight with an enemy that has full plate armor and a big greatsword.

I want to make it a really hard fight but I am thinking that maybe a greatsword is not the right choice for his enemy. Wouldn't that put him at too big a disadvantage? I am thinking that maybe it would be hard to believe that he could parry that greatsword.

As for more information:

Hero is wearing light leather armor. He doesn't have a shield, but is capable of conjuring one using some of his magical power (he can do magic, but there is a limit to the "mana" he can use before needing to meditate to harness more).

He arrives on horseback, but I plan for the animal to be killed early in the combat. The rest of the fight will be on foot.

The hero is "champion" of the goddess of death. The sword he has is in fact a gift from her. He often channels his power into his blade making it stronger and more devastating.

The lady he is going to save is in fact the goddess. She betrayed another, more powerful god because she wanted to take his place. The god discovered and banished her. The opponent is guarding the place where she is being kept and tortured. Hero is also in love with her so he is willing to fight till the death.

Comment: What equipment does the hero have besides the [Carolingian longsword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viking_sword)? Specifically, does he have a shield? (The opponent very obviously cannot have a shield, because wielding a post-Renaissance greatsword needs two hands.) Does the hero know his stuff? Why are they fighting with swords? A post-Renaissance greatsword is a highly specialized weapon, hardly the weapon of choice for a duel. (And also unlikely to be used by a knight in full armor. It really is a specialized weapon, used by specially trained infantry soldiers.)

Comment: Is the mage's sword conjured or is it real? Can he conjure different weapons?

Comment: I have edited question to add more information.

Comment: @MartinHlavňa Thanks. I have changed the title to give more info. Also if a Carolingian longsword is a Viking sword they were typically used one-handed while a longsword is used two-handed.

Comment: I wouldn't change a thing. P. Rothfuss has a character in the Kingkiller Chronicles which he intentionally bases on intelligence. With power, speed and others you assume that he/she can beat a danger every time after beating it once. With intelligence you need to be clever again and again in different ways, keeping the excitement. You want to know how it happens this time. Your character faces a big foe. It now isn't a question if their powers are equal or the like. A question if he's intelligent enough to use what he has to beat the knight. Just don't resort to luck and it'll be edge of seat.

Comment: More information about the 'place' where they end up fighting would help. The Geography of the fighting space is a key issue. Is it open (e.g. a large empty hall ), is it closed (e.g. a series of small rooms connected by narrow corridors or a temple with many pillars and pews/steps etc.) Are they in garden with trees and a brook. That kind of thing. The opportunities to swing a two handed sword great sword area fewer in 'closed' situations compared to 'open.

Comment: This reads like a question about a fight that you want to have in your world rather a question about the fundamental facts of your world.

Comment: Please note that if you want to be historically accurate with the terms, a longsword was used primarily with both hands. Yes, it could be used with one hand, but it was more effectively used with both hands. People think of the term "longsword" as the "standard" one-handed sword because D&D popularizing the term, but that's not accurate. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wezckiWeAAI

Comment: The hero has a powerful magic sword, and can conjure shields, and can throw fire, *"and things like that"*; the opponent only has a regular sword; and you think the hero is at too much a disadvantage? What am I missing?

Comment: @Stef: As the question goes my main concern is melee part.

Comment: Thanks for all comments and answers

Comment: The question's really focused on story details irrelevant to your question or/and worldbuilding. Indeed, a character being in love isn't interesting in how the fight will go, so you should put it as side-note or surrounding context. It's really a shame, because it doesn't need much to be on-topic. A question about how likely a fight between (supposedly experienced) combattants with a longsword and specific magic vs one with a two handed-sword is about battle-tactics and equipment tech level, much more on-topic here. Focus on the facts, not the reasons of the facts!

Comment: There are factual elements missing to help in answering : Battle environment (flat, forest, hill, inside with little space? No focus on a single place, just a general condition : steep, open-space, kind of obstacles...), what spells can the mage cast exactly, and what amplitude of effect each spell has. Also, I would personally pick one side to focus more on the strengths/weaknesses of a weapon choice. E.g. : "What would be the best weapon against a mage duelist?"

Comment: @Tortliena: Sorry, I will keep that in mind for future. "Story parts" were added later after more context has been requested. Original question just had that Greatsword vs longsword/mage part. The "in love" part was just to hint why he would pick a fight in the first place.

Comment: @MartinHlavňa I haven't checked in the other comments much. If they ask about context, it's generally more on the conditions than the reasons ^^'. My point is, you can tell about story, but avoid mixing it too much with the question's core like you would put chocolate chips in your cookies. I personally like to put story bits either as clearly defined footnotes (if requested) or on a section on top, to give some flavour and intentions to the question. Anyhow, I won't bother you too much with it :).

Comment: The term "longsword" is very imprecise, because, as attested in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_swords#Classification_by_hilt_type) it meant different things (even as a historical reference) at different times. In the early 20th century it commonly referred to rapiers of the Renaissance and early fencing which would not have been able to parry a Claymore/Greatsword.  However, at other times, "longsword" has referred things such as Arming swords and Viking sword, both of which are sturdy enough to parry with a Claymore (though at possible disadvantage).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The Greatsword is a Handicap**

A greatsword is not a dueling weapon. Historically it was used mostly as anti-cavalry weapon, that is because it is too big to do anything but horizontal slices or two handed thrusts. Those are powerful attacks, enough to take down a horse, and also cover a lot of ground (range advantage) but in a duel it means its attacks are predictable and slower.

**The real question is whether you expect the mage to slice through his armor**

You cannot take down someone in heavy armour without attacking its armour gaps (not easily done with a longsword, you need fine control of the tip of your blade in order to hit a gap). The other way is just hitting hard to cause impact damage or wearing your opponent out, and given that you are a mage against a fighter, I assume you are not gonna outdo him physically.

**Use your sword to defend and your spells to attack**

You cannot damage him with the sword, but it has a nice range and can be used to keep enemy attacks at bay, saving precious mana. You focus at casting should be directed at what ever will cause pain, fire spells, or tire him out.

Comment: This is the only answer that makes sense.  If your hero is in decent shape and reasonably agile, he will simply be able to dodge & evade that knight who's carrying a extra 20 pounds or more of steel, and swinging a massive sword, until the knight collapses from exhaustion.  A few simple spells, such as making a foot stick to the ground, will speed the process.  Also note that there's a difference between blocking a sword stroke (which may get your sword broken, or knocked from your hand), and parrying, which redirects the blow using much less force.

Comment: *"Historically it was used mostly as anti-cavalry weapon"* - this is debated, as treatises don't really depict it in that role, and on the battlefield pikes and halberds were better against cavalry anyway. But greatswords were very often used by elite guards, so it seems its most important usage was as a crowd-control weapon, a few elite soldiers being able to hold back a bigger, less trained crowd. Treatises did feature fight against multiple opponents, and given its great reach, it seems to be the perfect riot control weapon (especially with the added prestige and psychological effects).

Comment: @Jamesqf https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-bnM5SuQkI A knight in armor is more agile then you think.

Comment: @blademan9999: Yes, but you certainly wouldn’t want to do physical exercise in armor, especially not in summer heat. I’d also like to see the guy in the video do all that while wearing an appropriate helmet with visor down.

Comment: @LuizPSR: Good answer. As far as I’m aware against a knight in armor you’d actually half-sword the longsword or use a dagger. You’d more or less want to grapple them, then strike one of the gaps in the armor.

Comment: "Historically it was used mostly as anti-cavalry weapon" in Asia yes, in Europe the two handed great sword really had it's heyday as an anti-armour weapon for use against pike formations in the late medieval period. Greatswords were often used as a ceremonial weapons as well. Arming swords (knights longwords) were traditionally the second deadliest weapon to other knights throughout the medieval period, they evolved with the armour of the time, lances came first, no armour ever forged could stop a straight hit.

Comment: *You cannot take down someone in heavy armour without attacking its armour gaps (not easily done with a longsword, you need fine control of the tip of your blade in order to hit a gap)* How about a precision-enhancing spell (or time control) to guide the tip in just the right place?

Comment: ". . .it is too big to do anything but horizontal slices or two handed thrusts." You can do a lot of things with a greatsword: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbNL_At0IVw

Comment: @jamesqf I think they were more like 8 lbs for a big one.

Comment: @Daron - I think that jamesqf meant that knight's *armor* was extra 20 lb (which is, I think, a bit on the lighter side), not the sword.

Comment: @Edheldil Oh you're right! Just me being a silly sausage (as usual).

Comment: RE: "**Use your sword to defend..**", this depends entirely on what kind of "longsword" it actually is.  A rapier cannot parry a Claymore, you would have to either dodge it (possible) or block it with a shield (painful at best).  Thus a rapier would not be useful, defensively. An Arming sword or a Viking sword (also called "longswords") could however parry a Claymore-sized sword, though possibly at some disadvantage.  OTOH, a rapier would make it easier to target the gaps and weak points of the plate armor.

Comment: @blademan9999: A knight in armor may well be more agile than you think I think, but will not be as agile as an equally well-conditioned individual NOT carrying around that extra weight.  And as pointed out, the typical knight is going to be wearing a gambeson (essentially a quilt) or other padding under that armor, so will be at risk of heat exhaustion in warm weather.  (And maybe even in cold: I can work up a good sweat cross-country skiing.)

Answer (score 7):

**The mage can’t afford for this to be a sword fight**

If the enemy is a knight and the person is question is a mage, making this a sword fight is a losing proposition. Your knight is probably stronger, better trained in sword fighting, and has armor to cover most of their mistakes. If the mage has no armor then he must either focus on casting shield while fighting or fight with little to no armor. The knight has every advantage in a sword fight, as such the mage needs to make sure this isn’t a sword fight.

There are two ways to do this, run and cast fire, or shield and cast fire. Due to the shield the mage has an advantage at range, and at worst this turns into ranged combat between a knight who might not be the best crossbow shot and a mage who is trained to throw fire balls.

Anything one handed will likely be knocked aside by a great sword, so unless the mage is much stronger than the knight he won’t be able to parry for long.

Answer (score 6):

**Grease**

Having no reference for what you consider a basic/intermediate spell I have defaulted to the Dungeons & Dragons spell list. The grease spell can be cast by most level 1 spellcasters.

This spell summons a puddle of slippery grease either on the ground or on an object. This is bad news for the knight since his metal boots have bad traction on the grease and his metal gauntlets have bad traction on the sword hilt.

Once our hero greases the ground under the knight's feet, the duel consists of the knight flopping around trying to get to his feet while haphazardly swinging his massive sword in arcs, while the mage tries to get in and stab through his visor or armpits without getting cleft in twain or slipping on the grease himself.

The *fight* is difficult because the knight is still almost invulnerable to sword blows, and the hero can still be cut in half by a single swing.

**Note:** If this fight is still too hard/easy for the hero, then simply adjust the level of slipperyness to make it easier/harder.

Comment: nice idea :) I will surelly consider this.

Comment: He also knows fire spells, so depending on if grease is flammable you have that also.

Comment: @CharlieHershberger sticking to DnD that part is a hotly debated question as well

Comment: @CharlieHershberger I imagine the armor (and padding) makes the knight resistant to fire unless it's really hot. Maybe he will burn the palms of his hands if he flops around for long enough? That would be bad for holding a sword.

Answer (score 6):

#### Greatsword vs Longsword is already balanced.

Both greatswords and longswords are already two-handed weapons; the greatsword is somewhat longer and heavier, but that doesn't mean that the guy with the greatsword is surely going to win, or that the longsword would be unable to parry the greatsword. If someone who's not an expert on medieval swords were to watch the fight, they may well not be able to tell the difference between the two types of sword.

If anything, having the smaller, lighter sword may prove to be an advantage if the weilder of the sword is skilled enough to take advantage of the marginally slower strikes of the greatsword, allowing them to parry and riposte.

Comment: If you know Czech, there's a great sketch with this theme ... https://youtu.be/bGKz58KsAB0

Answer (score 5):

**Go through your spell book... or serve your mistress.  Your choice.**

What we have in here?  *Conjure fire ants?*  Nah, he's too disciplined for that.  I think.  <strike>Nerf iron objects was removed due to game balance considerations</strike>.  *Leda's Liquefaction* might take the opponent down a notch.  A *kaleidoscope* spell could keep him swatting uselessly at a horde of nerds.  *Whoah*, wait a minute, an old packet of boosterspice fell out from between two pages... this book has seen some epic parties.  Take a whiff of that stuff and *prescience* his sword out of your face, and save your magic points for later!  But it's not *romantic*!

No, you're wielding a sword from the Goddess of Death, and you want to serve her absolutely.  What do you think you have to do?  Charge him, and die.  And come back.  And charge him.  And die.  And come back.  And tackle him, and die.  And come back, once again, by the woeful magic of that fateful blade, that restores life to those who die wielding it.  **Die by the sword, live by the sword!**  If you have to wait for the swordsman to die of old age, I promise you one thing -- in the end, Life perishes, and Death remains.

Comment: Nice medieval take on *Edge of Tomorrow*.

Comment: In the recent patch this resurrection exploit was changed to only work if the user is actively trying to be killed. You still need to be careful -- it might fail if they fall over during the duel and bang their head.

Answer (score 3):

If this fight is happening in an age before Benjamin Franklin and other scientists formalized our understanding of electrical conductivity, then your hero can easily defeat the villain by casting a lightning bolt at that great sword shaped lightning rod that he is holding, but he might not know that he can do that, yet...

So he starts the fight as an underdog, trying to block a great sword with his toothpick sized long sword.  After it flies from his hand during the first clash of steel, he can run away a bit, relying on his enemies armor encumberment to stay out of sword range.  When the enemy inevitably corners him, he can use the shield spell to deflect the killing blow, then escape back out of range as his foe recovers from confusion over his sword hitting the spell's invisible barrier.  Better yet, if the foe was charging blade point first at the cornered hero, the shield spell might defer that point into some bulky wooden object.  The sword might then be stuck for long enough for the hero to retreat.
At some point, late in the process of loosing this fight, the hero might randomly cast the lightning spell, maybe just hoping to blind the knight.  But then the blue sparks crackle across the conductive plate armor as the knight inside screams and cooks.  The hero will have won a hopeless battle by shear luck and the as-of-yet undiscovered power of electricity.

Comment: "the blue sparks crackle across the conductive plate armor and..." the opponent just notes the strong smell of ozone, because a Faraday cage protects its insides from the lightning bolt.

Comment: For reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vheyKyV8vSA, a simple chicken wire overall will work just fine, even more so a plated armor.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, You've got a good point about the faradays cage protecting the occupant as long as the armor provides an unbroken path from lightning bolt to ground but with all the primitive joints, hand-shaped chainmail linkages and leather padding, there is a pretty good chance that there are some faults in there somewhere.  I certainly wouldn't want to be wearing armor in a lightning storm.

Answer (score 3):

**Sword from the Death Goddess.**

1. Hero realizes he is outmatched.
2. Hero is able to duck greatsword a couple of times.  Parry does not work.  Hero cannot hurt knight thru armor.
3. Hero tries spells.  Spells slow down knight but are not going to be enough.
4. Hero's sword is a gift of the Death Goddess.  /He often channels his power to blade making it stronger and more devastating./.  Hero channels power and calls on the sword, for real this time.  He blocks the greatsword.  The greatsword dies, crumbling into rust.  The Death sword looks different, scary.  He points it at the knight.
5. The knight, weapon lost, faced by black flames sword, yields.  He leaves.  Which works out because the mage's sword itself dies about 45 seconds after that.

---

We are going to see this knight again.  Maybe not as an opponent.

Comment: Is this an answer for worldbuilding or to create the plot?

Answer (score 2):

The balance of this fight really depends on what you mean by "greatsword" and if the "longsword" in question is period appropriate to the armour the knight is wearing.

"Greatsword" is not a term modern armourers generally use rather we describe swords as two-handed [insert model of sword here] because they were simply oversized versions of the many, varied, one-handed forms available, there is an exception that we talk about shortly. Many two-handed swords were simply for show but in the late medieval period a sword was created that was specialised as a two-handed weapon, a true greatsword called the [zweihänder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zweih%C3%A4nder). Where the oversized two-handed swords of earlier eras were clumsy by comparison with their one-handed versions the zweihänder is a light and nimble as well as a powerful blade, the product of late-medieval/early renaissance advances in metallurgy and fully capable of crippling men in full plate.

"Longsword" is another term that doesn't actually mean much in terms of describing the characteristics of the weapon; every sword from the Viking era through to the ceremonial swords still used by militaries the world over fall into the basic parameters. As such one can see that longswords have changed continually through the ages in response to advances in armour and the changing demands of the battlefield. The arming sword, or ["knightly sword"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knightly_sword), was no exception to this rule of changing form and in fact remained the second dealiest weapon when knights met each other in combat, bested only by lance from horseback.

If the knight is using some oversized ceremonial blade and the mage is using an arming sword specialised to the knight's armour I feel sorry for the man in the tin suit. Similarly a knight with a zweihänder against a man with an ill suited one-handed sword simply *will* win unless something goes badly wrong for him because an inappropriately shaped blade won't be able to penetrate the knight's armour no matter how it is used.

There are some simple, probably inexpensive, tricks the mage could try as well. Heat exhaustion is the greatest enemy of anyone in armour, even in modern reenactments people have died of heat stroke on cold days. Heating the knight's armour even slightly will make this worse. The other trick is bright light, from experience I can tell you that a knight's helm doesn't let one see out particularly well in the first place, and if you up the contrast the outside world turns into a blur of bright light, coloured shapes and occasional shadows. If the mage can blast the knight in the face with a really bright flash he stands a good chance of dazzling him for several seconds, long enough to do some serious damage.

Answer (score 0):

I would first start with, there are soo, soo, soo many ways where a fighter-mage could gain the upper hand (relatively easily) especially since you only say, "he must first fight with an enemy", and don't mention why he would close the range / distance (or why he'd let his horse get killed) or terrain at all.?.  But if the Mage has any agency in those aspects, he's soo many options:

- Cast Heat Metal on either the sword and/or armor
- Cast Sleep on the fighter
- Cast Light into the fighter's eyes
- Cast Magic Missle (who knows, depending on the level & roll might work)
- Prep an illusionary floor over a pit containing spikes (& a Rust Monster ) and have the fighter chase him around a corner & fall in
- Heck, just invite your neighborhood friendly Rust Monster to the fight

... all of which can be done at some distance ... there's no reason for the Mage to close that distance until he has the advantage.

I could go on, & on ... but in general, if the Mage is creative (& barring a giant disparance on level/HP or some really bad rolls) the Mage should be able to even the playing field, if not gain the advantage.

Answer (score 0):

When I first read this question title, I assumed you were trying to find a way for the knight to beat the mage.

Magic and melee are entirely different approaches to life, usually the mage just needs to find some high ground and turn the fighter into a boil in the can dinner.

- [Blink](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blink) and variants thereof are considered fairly basic spells used to keep out of melee range.
- [Frost](https://classic.wowhead.com/spell=12544/frost-armor) and fire armours are equally standard options that respectively slow or harm the attacker while protecting the caster.

As a general rule the simple fighter with nothing more than a sword (with or without board) is the one at a disadvantage in a fight with a caster. The only rule is remember to foreshadow any spells you use so you're not pulling them out of the bag on the day.

The simplest option would be to freeze his feet in place then cook him in his can.

Comment: interesting, I was of the opinion of the opposite in that he wanted the 'hero' to win.

Comment: @George2.0Hope, ah yes, but usually the idiot who turns up to the mage fight with only a knife is the hero and it's the villain who gets the magic.